# Do strobes on top of school buses improve safety?

Tags: united-states, road-vehicles, safety

#### Background

In many states of the USA, school buses are fitted with a "[roof-mounted strobe](http://www.schoolbusfleet.com/article/611297/roof-strobes-draw-crucial-attention)".

In some states, they are required by law:

> Mike Simmons, state director in Arkansas, says that the state's School Bus Safety Act of 1995 mandated that all school buses be equipped with a strobe as well as a crossing arm beginning July 1, 1997.

In some states they are not required, but often found:

> Some states that don't require the strobes still see widespread use of them. For instance, Indiana doesn't have a strobe mandate, but state director Pete Baxter says that a survey in 2000 found that about 78 percent of the state's school buses were equipped with them.

The local states also vary about the conditions under which they may be used.

> In California, school bus drivers may only use the strobes when visibility is reduced to 500 feet or less due to such atmospheric conditions as fog, rain, snow, smoke or dust. The conditions do not include the darkness between a half-hour after sunset and a half-hour before sunrise.
>
> In Michigan, school bus drivers may only use the strobes during inclement weather, loading or unloading of passengers, hindrance in visibility of the bus or, unlike California, a half-hour after sunset until a half-hour before sunrise.

#### Safety Claims

There are claims that these devices improve safety:

> Kent Chapman, who handles fleet maintenance and dispatching at the district, says the strobes' benefit is clear. "It's an attention-getter — it makes [motorists] aware that there's a vehicle ahead that is probably traveling slowly," he says.

Is there good evidence to support the claim that roof-mounted strobes on school buses improve safety?

Comment: I've made a significant edit to this question to bring it inline with community standards. If there is a lot more context than usual, it is because I have never seen or heard of these things before, and I needed it explained to me!

Comment: @Oddthinking Fine with the edits, thank you. I guess my point is that people seem to come up with ideas that they think will "help" but they either have no discernible effect, or it is not a worthwhile benefit compared to the problems it causes. Because you cannot prove harm, everyone gets to weigh in with their improvement ideas and cannot be gainsaid. I think this is just dumb. Individual cases of benefit are not what we base our laws and policy on, or else there would have to be a set of books for every citizen, because one man's meat is another man's poison, often quite literally.

Comment: Another thought: Don't school buses usually drive slowly and stop often when they are in residential neighborhoods, and drive fast and not stop when they are on multilane busy roads? In other words: the buses are doing something that is not that unusual. The problem is the people who feel the need to go 20 over the limit in a residential area. Those people should not be driving. Enough tickets, and they are off the roads.

Comment: Sure, but that is all your political opinion, which is off-topic.

Comment: @Oddthinking I guess I thought that the idea behind skepticism is to kill truly bad ideas by any means necessary, short of actually lying. The idea that we can "solve" or "help" a problem by addressing some side-feature of the issue is not very good. Perhaps this is the definition of "Politics"?

Comment: @nocomprende - I lurk here more than post, so I may be wrong, but: You say 'kill truly bad ideas', but applying a 'good' or 'bad' label is an *opinion*. As per the [Tour](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour), (emphasis mine): *"Skeptics is a question and answer site for **applying scientific skepticism...** ...we're working together to build a library of detailed answers **challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.**"* I would say that Skeptics.SE tries to remain neutral when approaching claims, only drawing conclusions from the facts presented.

Comment: Do the strobes  increase risk to other road users, by getting the drivers to look at the school buses to much?

Comment: @Ian Ringrose +1 for that! I myself had many, many uncomfortable situations with strobing bicycle lights.

Comment: @Robotnik I don't think we need to remain neutral. Promote good ideas. Eliminate bad ideas. If an idea is mediocre, it is bad, because it is keeping a good idea from emerging. Skepticism should ruthlessly eliminate anything that does not well promote improvement. That is not an opinion, it is called evolution.

Comment: Let's take this to [chat].

Comment: Lots of eyeballs, no Answers or substantive Comments after a week. The Buddha said, "*Greed for views tends not to edification.*" Words to live by. Perhaps the **absence of evidence is** *evidence that this is just a dumb idea that seized hold of peoples' minds and they could not reasonably refute it or dismiss the suggestion without seeming to be against safety, apple-hood and mother-pie so they just went along and kept quiet*? (Hmm. That is not a very concise way of putting it... I'll have to work on a better phrase.)

Comment: Still nothing new added after 3+ months. I guess that strobes really do not improve safety. Laws should be 'preened' to remove ineffective wishful thinking.